# X Axis Label Steps Interval in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo-UI. I could not able to set the x axis steps in 0.1 intervals(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4, etc.). It gives 0.2 as default (steps:1). Does any body knows how to make 0.1 interval?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
    { type: "scatter", data: [[1, 2]] }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      steps: 1
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/onuwu

Comment: I'm unable to load dojo.telerik.com/onuwu. Can you post some code in your question?

Comment: It looks like kendo just figures out based on the data where to zoom in. `skip` and `step` on the labels just control where to show the labels...so if the grid is going by `.2` and you have `step: 2` it will only show every other label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to set `majorUnit: .1` as a property on the `xAxis`.

http://dojo.telerik.com/onuwu/4

Their documentation isn't the easiest to find stuff in, but it's probably good to read through if you're doing a lot of work with charts. Here's the bit on [`valueAxis.majorUnit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis.majorUnit).

```js
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
    { type: "scatter", data: [[1, 2]] }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    majorUnit: .1
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @redbmk. I have been looking that feature for a while. I am new to that development platform. valueAxis and xAxis are identical? All their properties are same?

Comment: I have one more question regarding kendo ui capability. Is it possible to create a single signal with multiple color as similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143651/d3-js-dc-js-different-colored-line-segments-for-single-line-in-line-graph

Comment: I found a reference to the `xAxis` in the [chart docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-xAxis). It says it "supports all [valueAxis](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis) options".

Comment: Thanks a lot @redbmk, that is very useful information.

Comment: This is an example using bar charts, but I'm sure the same idea would work with a "scatter" or anything else. Basically you have an extra field in the data containing the color you want and in the series you tell it which field to use for the color, using `colorField`: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/local-data-binding